# How to make a proper Reaction Time Simulation with LED's, Button commands, and the Timing

Tags: python, python-3.x

So for my reaction time assignment, I ran to multiple issues such as when the timer ended, the red light won't light up nor print out the message saying the user has failed and when I press enter after the timer goes out, I can still press the button and it would light up the green LED and print out the message. The whole point of the assignment is to set up the random timer from 5-10 seconds to press the yellow led before it runs out and give out the total amount of time that the user had gotten when they pressed the button till it runs out and I wonder how to properly do it.

```
import physense_emu
import time
import random

sensor = physense_emu.Sensor()

#Greeting user to press "enter" to start the reaction time simulator
strtTime = "Start"
#Setting up simulator to start when pressing "enter"
butbucket = input("Press Enter")
strtTime = time.time()
randVal = random.randint(5, 11)
sensor.output("yled", "on")
time.sleep(5)
sensor.output("yled", "off")

stpTime = time.time()
btnStp = "Button_3"

#Setting up reaction time system to light up "green" if user is fast enough to push a button, but if not, then it'll light up "red"
while True:
 if (sensor.input(btnStp) == "pressed"):
     totalTime = stpTime - strtTime
     if totalTime < 10:
         sensor.output("gled", "on")
         time.sleep(3)
         sensor.output("gled","off")
         print("Congrats, you passed!")
     else:
         sensor.output("rled", "on")
         time.sleep(3)
         sensor.output("rled", "off")
         print("I'm sorry, but you failed to react quick enough!")
         break
```